# Axiom of choice on function

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a choice function to find an inverse for $F\colon A\to P(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247609/using-a-choice-function-to-find-an-inverse-for-f-colon-a-to-pb)

Let $F:A \rightarrow  \mathcal P (B)$ be arbitary functions which covers $B$.

Use AC to show there is a function 
$\phi: B \rightarrow A$
 such that $b \in F( \phi(b))$
for each $b \in B$ .

Do I use AC on the set B. I don't see what I'm choosing here.

Comment: I think I answered this recently. On the iPhone, it's simpler to answer than to find duplicates... :-/

Answer (score 2):

For every $b\in B$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $b\in F(a)$. You need to choose such $a$ for every $b$.

Comment: I think I get it now. So $I=B$ and so we make a set $A_i = \{ a | i \in F(a)\}$. So we choice function is the $\phi$.

Comment: @simplicity: Yes, that’s exactly right.